# How to do KDE(kernel density estimation) independently with seaborn?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I got a `DataFrame` with 3 labels, and KDE was plotted with code below.

Theoretically, the three lines should plot gaussian distributions, and calculus to 1 independently. However, the plotting shows that their density may be estimated jointly.

How should I estimate them independently? And got three gaussian distribution lines with equal calculus?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=['label', 'score'])
l = sns.displot(data=df, x="score",hue="label", kind="kde", rug=False)
```

[image]

Comment: See [seaborn histplot and displot output doesn't match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68865538/7758804)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per `sns.displot` [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.displot.html#seaborn.displot), using `kind = 'kde'` it also accepts arguments from `sns.kdeplot` function. In that case, you can see you have an argument `common_norm` available, [which is defined as](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html):

> If True, scale each conditional density by the number of observations
> such that the total area under all densities sums to 1. Otherwise,
> normalize each density independently.

So, you just need to add `common_norm = False` to your `sns.displot()` call.

Default behavior on seaborn tips dataset:

[image]

After setting `common_norm = False`:

[image]